# Compare two data frames to populate the Days range in r

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, match

I have Two data frames DF1 and DF2, I need to compare the Days from DF1 with respect to LOW Range and HI Range columns from DF2 and get the Days Range column in the resulting data frame.

```
Items=c("Vegetables","Fruits","Grocery","Dairy Product")
Days=c(16,5,41,25)
DF1=data.frame(Items,Days)

Low_Range=c(0,8,15,22,31,61)
Hi_Range=c(7,14,21,30,60,90)
Days_Range=c("within 7 days","8 to 14 days","15 to 21 days","22 to 30 days","31 to 60 days","61 to 90 days")
DF2=data.frame(Low_Range,Hi_Range,Days_Range)

Days_Slot=c("15 to 21 days","within 7 days","31 to 60 days","22 to 30 days")
DF_Result=data.frame(Items,Days,Days_Slot)
```

DF_Result will be my Resulting data frame with Days_Slot as new column added to DF1.
Can anyone Help to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved by *updating in a non-equi join*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1)[setDT(DF2), on = .(Days >= Low_Range, Days <= Hi_Range), 
           Days_Slot := Days_Range][]
```

> ```
>            Items Days     Days_Slot
> 1:    Vegetables   16 15 to 21 days
> 2:        Fruits    5 within 7 days
> 3:       Grocery   41 31 to 60 days
> 4: Dairy Product   25 22 to 30 days
> ```

Note that `DF1` is updated *by reference*, i.e., the new column `Days_Slot` is appended to `DF1` without copying the object.

---

As the intervals are contiguous, the matching `Days_Range` can be determined also by a *rolling join*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1)
setDT(DF2)
DF1[, Days_Slot := DF2[DF1, on = .(Low_Range = Days), roll = TRUE]$Days_Range][]
```

> ```
>            Items Days     Days_Slot
> 1:    Vegetables   16 15 to 21 days
> 2:        Fruits    5 within 7 days
> 3:       Grocery   41 31 to 60 days
> 4: Dairy Product   25 22 to 30 days
> ```

Again, a new column `Days_Slot` is appended to `DF1` *by reference*.

By the way, a *backward rolling join* will give the same result:

```
DF1[, Days_Slot := DF2[DF1, on = .(Hi_Range = Days), roll = -Inf]$Days_Range][]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fuzzyjoin`.

```
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(DF1, DF2,
                           by = c('Days' = 'Low_Range', 'Days' = 'Hi_Range'), 
                           match_fun = c(`>=`, `<=`))

#          Items Days Low_Range Hi_Range    Days_Range
#1    Vegetables   16        15       21 15 to 21 days
#2        Fruits    5         0        7 within 7 days
#3       Grocery   41        31       60 31 to 60 days
#4 Dairy Product   25        22       30 22 to 30 days
```

If your dataset is huge you may also try `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1)
setDT(DF2)

DF2[DF1, on = .(Low_Range <= Days, Hi_Range >= Days)]
```